# Django: How do I check if a User has already read/seen an article?

Tags: python, django, model

I am building a web-application for my senior design project with Python and Django. I have a user model that is able to read/write articles to display on the website. I have some tasks I want to accomplish.

1. I want to make it so that if an article is accessed (read) by a user, it is indicated for only that user that the article has been previously accessed. If I were to log into a brand new user account, the same article wouldn't be indicated as "accessed" for the new account.
2. How would I be able to present on the front-end side that the article has been viewed by the user logged in? (ie: make the article title bolded or a different color to indicate its been already visited)

Below are my models and views:

**User model**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, max_length=255, blank=False)
    university = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    newsletter_subscriber = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_email_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        default=False,
        help_text=(
            'Designates whether the user can log into '
            'this admin site.'
        ),
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        default=True,
        help_text=(
            'Designates whether this user should be '
            'treated as active. Unselect this instead '
            'of deleting accounts.'
        ),
    )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

**Article model**

```
class Article(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False)
    journal = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    URL = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class MetaData:
        ordering = ['-created']
```

**Article detail view**

```
class ArticleDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Article
    context_object_name = 'articles'
    template_name = 'home/article_detail.html'
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extra table.

```
class ArticleSeenRecord(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("django.contrib.auth.models.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And then in your article view, create a new record when one doesn't exist, for that article combined with the authenticated user.

```
class ArticleDetail(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Article
    context_object_name = 'articles'
    template_name = 'home/article_detail.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        obj =  super().get_object(queryset)
        record, created =  ArticleSeenRecord.objects.get_or_create(user=self.request.user, article=obj)
        return obj
   

class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    def seen_by_user(self, user):
         return self.atricleseenrecord_set.objects.filter(user=user).exists()
```

I added the extra function here. You will also need to add a template tag which you can ideally copy from this example

```
@register.simple_tag
def article_seen_by_user(article, user):
    return article.seen_by_user(user)
```

For further guidance on how to use and register custom template tags, please refer to this page of the documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/

Specifically this section:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.simple_tag

Comment: This makes sense intuitively. But if I were to create a new record when one doesn't already exist in the view, wouldn't that make the article have the record for all users?

Comment: I updated my answer. Does this make more sense?

Comment: Also, replace the foreign key to User, to you abstract user model too

Comment: Youre using an abstract user class here, which extends and replaces djangos built in one, and so the foreign key should point to your user model. I will update my answer for how to display in template

Comment: Updated my answer to accommodate the extra question. Please add this to the body of your question so people can find it if they want to ask a similar question

Comment: Is there a way this could be implemented without the use of filter? I'd like to just display all the articles at once and maybe indicate the visited ones by changing the title of the text to bold or perhaps a different color

Comment: This does exactly that. You could add a ManyToMany relationship on Article directly to User and call it users_seen field. Then you can check if a user is in that relationship. However, I think my original answer is a lot more explicit and makes more sense. If there are lots of articles, you probably want to paginate them instead of worrying about filtering each iteration in the template as the time taken has a negligible effect